# What is the math behind the SVG <feTurbulence> filter?

Tags: math, svg, random, noise, svg-filters

I'm currently writing a simple SVG interpreter (not exhaustive of course, this would be pretty complicated), and I find myself struggling with the **<feTurbulence>** filter.

Basically, there are two types of noise that may be generated :

- **fractalNoise** is actually pretty simple to generate, since the original Perlin noise generator can be used (sample code may be found [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) for example).
- **turbulence** is the default filter, and at first I thought that the only important factor would be that the noise is divergence-free, so I tried applying ∇ x f to a vector field with only the z component non-null, to get a divergence-free 2D random vector field (since ∇.(∇ x f) = 0). The issue is that the resulting noise looks nothing like it's supposed to.

Here is what chrome generates using *fractalNoise* and *turbulence* (from [here](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/02/19/svg-filter-effects-creating-texture-with-feturbulence/)) :

[The images generated by chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx6Ir.png)

And here are the noises I'm able to generate with the math I described above :

[My fractal noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC4jD.png)

[My first try at turbulent noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVYIJ.png)

There are a lot of issues here. First of : in the noise generated by the SVG interpreter, I'm not sure that I understand what the colors represent. The fractal noise seems "brigther" than mine, although they both share the same "quality" (mine goes from 0 to 1 on all color channels).

As for the turbulent noise, generating a 2D field means that I only have 2 components to work with, not 3, but most importantly I'm certain that this is not how the actual turbulent noise is generated. Does anyone know what is the math for this noise generator ?

Thanks !

Comment: You might be running into issues with color-spaces. The default color space for SVG filters is linear-RGB - unlike the sRGB color space - which is used everywhere else in CSS. If you add "color-interpolation-filters=sRGB" to your filter element, you might get something that matches what you expect. The exact math can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html#feTurbulenceElement

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot ! The interpreter I'm writing is actually in OpenGL / GLSL, and I'm using fragment shaders for generating the noise images. All the math is done in linear color space and the conversion to sRGB is only performed at the end, so the color space shouldn't be an issue... As for the code, thank you so much, I'll check it out :)

Comment: Alright, so I read the code, and if I don't take into account the stitching part (which may actually be the really important part) it seems like the **turbulence** function is actually just octaved noise. Which is pretty much the code I already have written in GLSL. is the *turbulence* feTurbulence type type just a simple modification of the octaved Perlin noise (by taking an absolute value for example) ? I'll post my GLSL code in an answer to the original question.

Comment: Chromium lib for perlin noise if it's any help: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/skia/src/shaders/SkPerlinNoiseShader.cpp?q=SkPerlinNoiseShader&ss=chromium                                                 /**
They're not 2 entirely different noises. The output looks different, but once the noise is generated in the [1, -1] range, the output is brought back in the [0, 1] range by doing :
     *  kFractalNoise_Type : noise * 0.5 + 0.5
     *  kTurbulence_Type   : abs(noise)
     */

Comment: Oooooh thanks ! so that's what I understood, it seems to work now :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here is the GLSL code I'm using for generating octaved Perlin noise (modified from [rosettacode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Perlin_noise#GLSL), and no normalization/parametrization has already been done) :

```
uniform float time;

mat3 rotation(float angle, vec3 axis){
    float c = cos(angle);
    float s = sin(angle);

    float t = 1 - c;
    float x = axis.x;
    float y = axis.y;
    float z = axis.z;

    return mat3(
        vec3(t * x * x + c,      t * x * y - s * z,  t * x * z + s * y),
        vec3(t * x * y + s * z,  t * y * y + c,      t * y * z - s * x),
        vec3(t * x * z - s * y,  t * y * z + s * x,  t * z * z + c)
    );
}

float rand(vec3 c){
    return fract(sin(dot(c, vec3(12.9898, 78.233, 32.43983))) * 43758.5453);
}
 
float noise(vec3 p, float freq){
    float unit = 1000/freq;
    p = rotation(rand(vec3(23.473, -128.437, 23.439)) * 6.28318531,
        normalize(vec3(rand(vec3(-2, 3, 1)), rand(vec3(23.2, 47.3, 82.8)), rand(vec3(-239.3, -4.3, 2.59))))) * p;
    vec3 ij = floor(p/unit);
    vec3 xy = mod(p,unit)/unit;
    xy = .5*(1.-cos(3.1415926535*xy));
    float a = rand((ij+vec3(0.,0.,0.)));
    float b = rand((ij+vec3(1.,0.,0.)));
    float c = rand((ij+vec3(0.,1.,0.)));
    float d = rand((ij+vec3(1.,1.,0.)));
    float e = rand((ij+vec3(0.,0.,1.)));
    float f = rand((ij+vec3(1.,0.,1.)));
    float g = rand((ij+vec3(0.,1.,1.)));
    float h = rand((ij+vec3(1.,1.,1.)));
    float x1 = mix(a, b, xy.x);
    float x2 = mix(c, d, xy.x);
    float x3 = mix(e, f, xy.x);
    float x4 = mix(g, h, xy.x);
    float y1 = mix(x1, x2, xy.y);
    float y2 = mix(x3, x4, xy.y);
    return mix(y1, y2, xy.z);
}
 
float pNoise(vec3 p, int res){
    float persistance = .5;
    float n = 0.;
    float normK = 0.;
    float f = 4.;
    float amp = 1.;
    int iCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<50; i++){
        n+=amp*noise(p, f);
        f*=2.;
        normK+=amp;
        amp*=persistance;
        if (iCount == res) break;
        iCount++;
    }
    float nf = n/normK;
    return nf;
}

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(
        pNoise(vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(57349.4387, -1271.45738), time), 4),
        pNoise(vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(9453.32748, 23875.43473), time), 4),
        pNoise(vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(-28574.323, 125943457.3), time), 4), 1);
}
```

After further testing, and checking out the code, it really seems like the actual turbulence is only perlin noise in the [-1, 1] range, whose absolute value is then taken.

For reference, here is the image i'm getting with this method :

[the result of my turbulence filter using an absolute value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqPCz.jpg)

And a turbulent displacement example from my code :

[A turbulence displacement example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3URCw.png)

Thanks !